# How can I check for reference equality in Perl?

Tags: perl

In Perl, how can I check for pointer equality of two different mutable objects?

Since almost everything is mutable in Perl, there might be times when it is desirable to know when two objects are identical – that is, modifying one will effect the other.  How can one do that?

Edit: By "object" I mean any Perl value.  This includes strings, arrays, hashes, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you know both values are references, you can use the numeric equality operator `==` to compare them.

If you aren't sure that both values are references, you can test them with `ref` first.

```
if (ref($x) and ref($y) and $x==$y) {
  print "\$x and \$y are references to the same thing.\n"
}
```

This is documented in [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Using-References), which says

> Using a string or number as a reference produces a symbolic reference, as explained above.  Using a reference as a number produces an integer representing its storage location in memory.  The only useful thing to be done with this is to compare two references numerically to see whether they refer to the same location.

Comment: I would also like to know if two arrays are the same array, two hashes are the same hash, etc.

Comment: Do you often have arrays that are the same array with different names? I think usually this would only come up with references. Of course it is possible to make different names refer to the same array with stuff like `*a=\@b`. In that case I think you could still use reference comparison: `\@a == \@b`

Comment: Note: That won't work for objects that overload numification

Comment: Note: To check if changing one variable could change another, one also wants to check for magic

Comment: If you have two arrays, you wouldn't want to just check if the arrays are the same, but whether they share any elements.

Answer (score 5):

> *there might be times when it is desirable to know when two objects are identical – that is, modifying one will effect the other. How can one do that?*

Here's an example of where such a check is used:

```
*d = \$x;              # Makes $d an alias for $x.
($x, $y) = ($y, $x);   # Requires creating temporary copies.
($x, $y) = ($m, $n);   # Usually simple ($x=$m; $y=$m;)
($x, $y) = ($c, $d);   # Requires creating temporary copies.
```

You can see that check [here](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/be2c0c650b028f54e427f2469a59942edfdff8a9:/pp_hot.c#l1268).

Not only do you want to check if both "objects" are the same, you want to check if they're magical. In the above example, the variables on the LHS are checked for "set" magic, and the variables on the RHS are checked for "get" magic.

To check if assigning to `$dst` could change `$src`, use the following:

```
use B            qw( svref_2object SVs_GMG SVs_SMG );
use Scalar::Util qw( refaddr );

sub SvGMAGICAL { !!( svref_2object($_[0])->FLAGS & SVs_GMG ) }
sub SvSMAGICAL { !!( svref_2object($_[0])->FLAGS & SVs_SMG ) }

sub could_be_common {
   my ($dst_ref, $src_ref) = @_;
   my $dst_addr = refaddr($dst_ref) or die("usage");
   my $src_addr = refaddr($src_ref) or die("usage");
   return $dst_addr == $src_addr || SvSMAGICAL($dst_ref) || SvGMAGICAL($src_ref);
}

say could_be_common($dst, $src);
```

Or for the above example,

```
sub could_be_common {
   my ($dst_ref, $src_refs) = @_;
   for my $dst_ref (@$dst_refs) {
      return 1 if SvRMAGICAL($dst_ref);
   }

   for my $src_ref (@$src_refs) {
      return 1 if SvGMAGICAL($src_ref);
   }

   for my $dst_ref (@$dst_refs) {
      my $dst_addr = refaddr($dst_ref);
      for my $src_ref (@$src_refs) {
         return 1 if $dst_addr == refaddr($src_ref);
      }
   }

   return 0;
}

say could_be_common([ \$x, \$y ], [ \$c, \$d ]);
```

Comment: Not sure if it matters, just pointing out that these `perl -E` samples defeat syntax highlighting :)